# How should I deadhead my peace lily?

Tags: pruning, peace-lily, deadheading

From my research I've found that I'm supposed to cut the dead flowers at the bottom of the stem, but as the stem of the flower goes down it becomes wrapped in a leaf stem. I'm looking at a couple options here:

- Cut the flower stem where it becomes wrapped in a leaf stem
- Cut the leaf stem it comes from
- Try to remove the flower stem from the leaf stem in order to cut it farther down

I'm not sure which one of these would be best for the plant.

Answer (score 1):

Spathiphylums are interesting in that the "flower" is a lightly modified leaf.  As they will flower in lower light they are popular for indoor plants.  This picture from [David Darling](http://www.daviddarling.info/encyclopedia/S/spathe.html) shows the parts of the flower
[image]

If you want to get the most out of the flower remove the spadix when the spathe opens. This avoids the pollen dropping and the spathe will remain white for much longer.  After weeks or months, depending on light levels, the spathe will die back and you can  cut it where it joins the leaf or just pull the whole thing away from the leaf.

You do not need to cut the leaf at all.